# Accessing the config.json in tileserver-gl-light from Ubuntu 20.04 server via command line

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, tile-server, tileserver-gl

I am trying to access the config.json file for Tileserver-gl-light from a command line on an Ubuntu 20.04 Server. I am new to this operating system and just cannot seem to find the file. From my understanding I can change the info via `sudo nano` but I cannot find the file in my system. I have a working server using tileserver-gl-light, but intend to change the default map of Zurich to one that better suits my project.

[This](https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/07/self-hosted-tile-server.html) is the tutorial I used when setting up the server, only deviating to set python3 to work as python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to `sudo nano config.json` and create my own config file.